# Correct order of deferred events in state-machine of UML 2.x

Tags: uml, state-machine

UML 2.x's state-machine diagram supports deferred events.
Here is the state-machine. [image: state-machine-diagram]

When I send e1, e2, e3, and e4 to the sm1 in this order, which is the expected state? If e1 is de-queued from the defer queue and en-queue again to the defer queue in s2, and e2 is consumed to transition to s3, the head of the defer queue is e3 in s3, so that the expected state is s5. However, If e1 keeps the original position (head) and skip it, then e2 is consumed, the expected state is s4.

Does the UML 2.x specification define which is correct?

Comment: Actually the 2.5 specs are very explicit on that. OMG even released a paper specifically for state machines: https://www.omg.org/spec/PSSM/About-PSSM/ Unfortunately it's not my domain so I can't answer the question.

Comment: I don't know what the spec says. But it'd find it weird behavior if the order of events in the deferred queue would be changed (by checks). I'd expect that deferred events stay in the queue and that the algorithm checks starting at the "old" end of the queue and works its way to the "young" end. If it finds a non-deferred event, it takes it out of the queue and processes it (possibly by discarding it). I cannot think of any situation where enqueue would make more sense - or any sense for a fact.

Comment: @Thomas Kilian, thank you for the document link. I didn't know the document. I will check it. In `ptc-17-04-04.pdf`, `9.3.16 Deferred` seems to be what I wanted to. At first, I got confused because there is no `/defer` notation, but now I understand  note(UML) `Deferes Continue` means `Continue/defer`. I don't know why the author doesn't use UML notation. Anyway, I will check the document covers my case.

Comment: @DrP3pp3r, thank you for the comment. You mean the state should be s4 after all events are processed because e1 is sent before e3. I think that it is reasonable. But I think the processing order of the deferred events might be unspecified in the UML spec. If it is unspecified, the state-machine library author can choose other way. Boost.MSM, C++ state-machine library that supports UML 2.x semantics, seems to de-queued and en-queued, so the final state is `s5`. Here is the test code https://wandbox.org/permlink/v5hRtdJXRek8RidW

Comment: @TakatoshiKondo. Yes, that's what I meant. I've got to check if [yasmine](http://yasmine.seadex.de) behaves correctly.

Comment: I also checked Boost(candidate) sml. It has the same issue as Boost.MSM https://wandbox.org/permlink/KTknkoeo8Mjobf2h so I reported the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the comments, I got the answer.

### Deferred event position

I use the word `defer queue` in the state-machine diagram, but there is no such concept in UML 2.5.1(latest) specification.

See the site:
https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/About-UML/

the file:
formal-17-12-05.pdf

UML 2.5.1 defines `event pool`.

In the `14.2.3.4.4 State history`,

--start quote

*Deferred Events*

A State may specify a set of Event types that may be deferred in that State. This means that Event occurrences of those types will not be dispatched as long as that State remains active. Instead, these Event occurrences remain in the event pool until:

- a state configuration is reached where these Event types are no longer deferred or,
- if a deferred Event type is used explicitly in a Trigger of a Transition whose source is the deferring State (i.e., a kind of override option).

An Event may be deferred by a composite State or submachine States, in which case it remains deferred as long as the composite State remains in the active configuration.

--end quote

The important point is "Instead, these Event occurrences **remain** in the event pool until". The word **remain** implies keeping the original position in the event pool.

### Event evaluation order

The events in the event pool has order.

See the site: https://www.omg.org/spec/PSSM/About-PSSM/

the file: ptc-17-04-04.pdf

`9.3.16.2 Deferred 001`, `RTC Steps` Step7 indicates that the event evaluating order is head("old") to tail("young").

### Conclusion

The event evaluation order in the event pool is head to tail. Deferred events are just remained their original position. Hence `e1` should be evaluated at `s3` in my diagram.

### Note

The Boost.MSM (version 1.68.0) implementation is not correct. https://wandbox.org/permlink/v5hRtdJXRek8RidW

I will report the issue about that.